# How to @connect to async loaded data?

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm writing an app with React, Redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux and redux-async-connect. The special part of the app is that all client-server communication is done over websockets.

My users can read/write several walls, that I store is a `walls` store with the following reducer and basic helper functions:

```
const LOAD = 'ws/wall/LOAD';
const LOAD_SUCCESS = 'estisia/wall/LOAD_SUCCESS';
const LOAD_FAIL = 'estisia/wall/LOAD_FAIL';
const ADD_MESSAGE = 'estisia/wall/ADD_MESSAGE';

const initialWallState = {
  loaded: false,
  messages: []
};

const initialState = {
  walls: {}
};

function wall(state = initialWallState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ... // omitted for brevity
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function walls(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  if (typeof action.data === 'undefined' || typeof action.data.wallId === 'undefined') return state;

  const newState = {
    ...state.walls,
    [action.data.wallId]: wall(state.walls[action.data.wallId], action)
  };
  return {walls: newState};
}

export function isLoaded(wallId, globalState) {
  return globalState.walls.wallId && globalState.walls.wallId.loaded;
}

export function load(wallId) {
  return {
    type: LOAD,
    send: ['wall/messages/page', [wallId, 1]]
  };
}
```

and I have a `Wall` container where the appropriate `wallId` is passed in by react-router, but can't figure out how to make the `@connect` call pass only the relevant wall data to the container. What should I do instead of the @connect meta-code below to get it working?

```
@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}, params}) => {
    if (!isLoaded(params.wallId, getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadWall(params.wallId));
    }
  }
}])
@connect(
  state => ({
    messages: state.wall[this.params.wallId].messages,
    loading: state.wall[this.params.wallId].loading
  }))
export default class Wall extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    messages: PropTypes.array
  }
... // omitted for brevity 
}
```

How can I achieve `redux-async-connect` to help me out with the above case?

Comment: Where are you expecting to get `this.params.wallId` from in your `@connect ` method?